# Ordering legend values ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I was trying to ordering the labels of a plot but no matter what I do it doesn't change.

This is a dummy data frame because mine is way to big but I would get the same result

```
df <- data.frame(treatment= c("C", "3", "4", "5", "10","HT"), 
                 day1 = c(0.23, 0.16, 0.34, 0.21, 0.17,0.34),
                 day2=c(0.18,0.13,0.27,0.17,0.11,0.23),
                 day4=c(0.15,0.08,0.20,0.14,0.05,0.17))
```

I plot it using this code

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-treatment, names_to = "days", names_prefix = "day") %>% 
  mutate(days = as.integer(days),
         treatment = as.factor(treatment)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(days, value, color = treatment)) +
  geom_line()+
  ylab(expression(Transpiration (g/h)))+xlab(expression(Days))+ theme_dark()+ theme(text = element_text(size = 20))
```

After this the legend order is 10,3,4,5,C,HT. So I tried to change to C,3,4,5,10,HT

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-treatment, names_to = "days", names_prefix = "day") %>% 
  mutate(days = as.integer(days),
         treatment = as.factor(treatment)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(days, value, color = treatment)) +
  geom_line()+
  ylab(expression(Transpiration (g/h)))+xlab(expression(Days))+ theme_dark()+ theme(text = element_text(size = 20))+
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks=c("C","3","4","5","10","HT"))
```

But I keep getting the same results. Any suggestions please? also how can I get the legend into the graph itself and delete the title of the legend. Thank you for all the help[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually provide the `limits` to the scale if you want a particular order. Also you're using a `fill` legend for a `colour` aesthetic, which probably explains  why your code wasn't working.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(treatment= c("C", "3", "4", "5", "10","HT"), 
                 day1 = c(0.23, 0.16, 0.34, 0.21, 0.17,0.34),
                 day2=c(0.18,0.13,0.27,0.17,0.11,0.23),
                 day4=c(0.15,0.08,0.20,0.14,0.05,0.17))

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-treatment, names_to = "days", names_prefix = "day") %>% 
  mutate(days = as.integer(days),
         treatment = as.factor(treatment)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(days, value, color = treatment)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_discrete(limits = df$treatment)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

To delete the title and place the legend inside the panel, you can use

```r
  scale_colour_discrete(limits = df$treatment, name = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = c(1, 1),
        legend.justification = c(1, 1))
```

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: How can I change the colors now since I am already using a scale_color function?

Comment: If you want to pick colours manually you can use `scale_colour_manual(limits = df$treatment, name = NULL, values = c("red", "blue", "green", ...))`.